# Get video URL with regex for current expire time and token

Tags: php, regex, token, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get a current video `URL` from a page. The video URL has `expire` time and `token` in this format: `http://cdn.videourl.mp4?expire=1635939248&token=7022dbc14de970c7uc040ac4f35058f0`

**This is what I got so far:**

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.videos.com/");

preg_match_all('/(http.*mp4\?[a-zA-Z]+=[0-9]+&[a-zA-Z]+=([0-9]+([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)+)',

    $html,
    $posts, // will contain the article data
    PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $link = $post[0];

echo $link;
}
```

With this regex `/(http.*mp4(.*?))/` I can get the url until the `.mp4`

What's missing in my regex to get the full `URL`? I also tried with this one (but I think something is missing...): `/(http.*mp4\?[a-zA-Z]+=[0-9]+&[a-zA-Z]+=([0-9]+([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)+)`

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9]+` could replace already this part `([0-9]+([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)+)`... this would make things probably easier already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php example, the regex contains an unclosed parenthesis at the start of the pattern. There are also delimiters missing for the pattern in `preg_match_all`

Given that the order of the querystring parameters is like this, you can use a capture group for the part after the first equals sign, and a single capture group after the second equals sign:

```
http\S*?\.mp4\?[a-zA-Z]+=([0-9]+)&[a-zA-Z]+=([0-9a-z]+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1jXhnV/1).

For example

```
$html = "http://cdn.videourl.mp4?expire=1635939248&token=7022dbc14de970c7uc040ac4f35058f0";

preg_match_all('/http\S*?\.mp4\?[a-zA-Z]+=([0-9]+)&[a-zA-Z]+=([0-9a-z]+)/',
    $html,
    $posts, // will contain the article data
    PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
);

var_export($posts);
```

Output

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'http://cdn.videourl.mp4?expire=1635939248&token=7022dbc14de970c7uc040ac4f35058f0',
    1 => '1635939248',
    2 => '7022dbc14de970c7uc040ac4f35058f0',
  ),
)
```

If the order of the parameters is not fixed, you could also use named capture groups with the same name and the `J` flag.

```
http\S*?\.mp4\?(?:expire=(?P<expire>[0-9]+)&token=(?P<token>[0-9a-z]+)|token=(?P<token>[0-9a-z]+)&expire=(?P<expire>[0-9]+))
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/JNT0Y).

---

Note that it might be easier to get the key values pairs using [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

For example

```
parse_str(parse_url($html, PHP_URL_QUERY), $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Output

```
array(2) {
  ["expire"]=>
  string(10) "1635939248"
  ["token"]=>
  string(32) "7022dbc14de970c7uc040ac4f35058f0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may very well use inbuilt functions instead:

```
<?php
$url = "http://cdn.videourl.mp4?expire=1635939248&token=7022dbc14de970c7uc040ac4f35058f0";

// parts
$parts = parse_url($url);
print_r($parts);

// query
parse_str($parts["query"], $query);
print_r($query);
?>
```

This yields

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => cdn.videourl.mp4
    [query] => expire=1635939248&token=7022dbc14de970c7uc040ac4f35058f0
)
Array
(
    [expire] => 1635939248
    [token] => 7022dbc14de970c7uc040ac4f35058f0
)
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/sPfbAT).